# Дату из JSON в CalendarView.MinDate

Tags: android, json, calendar-view

Получаю JSON:

```
[ 
   { 
      "minDate":"07\/21\/2017",
      "maxDate":"08\/01\/2017"
   }
]
```

Никак не могу сообразить, как эти даты записать в `CalendarView.MinDate` и `CalendarView.MaxDate` соответственно.

Вот код, возможно там написана чушь я учусь:

```
package com.androidjson.idrees_androidjsoncom;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class RecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    CalendarView calendarView;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    String StringHolder = "";

    // Добавление URL-адреса HTTP-сервера в строковую переменную.
    String HttpURL = "http://localhost/date_min_max.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

        // Вызов метода GetDataFromServerIntoTextView для установки данных JSon MySQL в TextView.
        new GetDataFromServerIntoTextView(RecordActivity.this).execute();

    }

    // Объявление метода GetDataFromServerIntoTextView с помощью AsyncTask.
    public class GetDataFromServerIntoTextView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        // Объявление CONTEXT.
        public Context context;


        public GetDataFromServerIntoTextView(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Добавление HttpURL к моему объекту HttpPost.
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(HttpURL);

            try {
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                StringHolder = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                // Передача переменной владельца строки в JSONArray.
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(StringHolder);
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            try {

                // Добавление строки JSOn в textview после завершения загрузки.
                textView.setText(jsonObject.getString("minDate"));

                //calendarView.setMinDate(jsonObject.getLong("minDate"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, у вас есть дата в формате `MMM/dd/yyyy` и вам нужно установить её как минимальную в вашем `CalendarView`?

Всё делается довольно просто:

```
// Парсим жсон
String json = "[{\"minDate\":\"07/21/2017\",\"maxDate\":\"08/01/2017\"}]";

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

String minDateString = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("minDate");
String maxDateString = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("maxDate");

// Парсим дату
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

Date minDate = formatter.parse(minDateString);
Date maxDate = formatter.parse(maxDateString);

// Получаем время
long minDateTime = minDate.getTime();
long maxDateTime = maxDate.getTime();

// Как-то инициализируете и работаете с этим
DatePickerDialog dpd;
DatePicker dp = dpd.getDatePicker();

// Устанавливаем даты
dp.setMinDate(minDateTime);
dp.setMaxDate(maxDateTime);
```

Comment: никак не соображу как прикрутить ваш код к своему((